# How to delete multiple records together using IN(of MySQL) in CakePHP 2.6

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cakephp-2.0

Basically, I want to do that user will check the checkbox and click on deleteAll button for delete multiple records at once. For this, i fire ajax  and get all selected id's and then selected id's send to controller's method.

I am using delete method for remove multiple records from database but it is not working.

And I do not want to delete multiple records using loop.

Is there any other way of CakePHP of delete multiple records at once?

I tried below code:

script.js :

```
$('#del_all').click(function(){
    var selected=[];
    $('.check:checked').each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

     $.ajax({
            type: "post",  
            url: "Users/deleteall", // URL to request
            data: {"id":selected},  // Form variables                  
            success: function(response){ 
                  alert(response);                 
            }
         });

});
```

Controller method :

```
public function deleteall(){
    $data=$this->request->data['id'];
    $user_ids=implode("','",$data);
    $user_ids="'".$user_ids."'";
    $this->User->delete($user_ids,$cascade=false);      
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this with `deleteall` try to use this

```
public function deleteall()
{
    $user=array(1,2,3);     // replace with real values
    $condition = array('User.id in' => $user);
    $this->User->deleteAll($condition,false);     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `deleteAll()` method

```
$this->User->deleteAll(array('id' => $user_ids), false);
```

Note that:

> `deleteAll()` will return `true` even if no records are deleted, as the conditions for the delete query were successful and no matching records remain.

More information you can find in [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html).

Comment: Hi marian0, deleteAll() is also not working.  According to document, deleteAll() will delete all records that match the supplied conditions but i am supplying multiple values on single fields. I want to use query like :   "delete * from users where id in('1','2','3');"  And how can i print the query on ajax request.

Comment: simply use an incorrect coloumn this will print query . :p this is just a trick .$this->User->deleteAll(array('ids' => $user_ids), false);. then rename the coloumn